# Java handling Resources in a Jar AND in the eclipse project

Tags: java, file, resources

Im very confused after reading many different information about my problem. Im writing a java game. Of course i have resources like pictures sounds and so on. Now i need a way, to get this files in a jar - when exported the project - but which also runs with the eclipse project. 
How i was scanning a folder until now:

```
f = new File(this.getClass().getResource("../" + soundArchive).toString().substring(5)).listFiles();
```

This is very confusing, unproffessional, and seems to dont work in a jar...

```
        InputStream i = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bgmusic.wav");
```

..is always returning null in the eclipse project...

So what is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: In order to get resources you need to have it on `PATH` and to be accessible by classloader. Eclipse set its own `PATH`.

Comment: "what" i have to have on which "path" ? :(

Comment: Sorry I meant `CLASSPATH`. Cannot the edit message now, though. Just ensure the file you want to be loaded is on classpath. You can check it at runtime with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`.

Comment: what exactly is the classpath? Im not a beginner, but i dont understand it....

Comment: but the file seems to be tbhere....

Comment: Well if you do not know what `CLASSPATH` is then I am not sure if you can be classified as not-a-beginner. You better learn something about it or else you will stumble upon similar problems often. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)